# ¿Por qué no se almacenan, o cargan, mis registros en la base de datos SQLite en Android Pie, y cómo lo soluciono?

Tags: c#, sqlite, android-sqlite, xamarin.android, android-pie

El proceso es el siguiente: La aplicación se instala; valida si es la primer ejecución; si lo es, crea la base de datos con sus respectivas tablas y 5 registros en una de ellas; almacena en preferencias que ya no es la primer ejecución. Una vez concluido ello, se pasa al Activity principal donde se muestran en un ListView los registros creados, **y se muestran**. El detalle es el siguiente: Pasado unos minutos, cerrada la aplicación, al volverla a abrir... ya no están los registros.

Cabe mencionar que en versiones anteriores a Android Pie todo funciona a la perfección (hasta la versión 6; en versiones anteriores no lo sé).

Mi conexión a la base de datos es esta forma:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        string libraryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string sqliteFilename = "db.db3";

        string path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
        conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
    }
}

public class Database
{
    readonly object locker = new object();
    SQLiteConnection database;

    public Database(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        database = conn;

        database.CreateTable<Tabla1>();
        database.CreateTable<Tabla2>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tabla1> GetDatos()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return (from i in database.Table<Tabla1>()
                    orderby i.Titulo ascending
                    select i).ToList();
        }
    }

    //Etcétera.
}
```

Leí algo sobre el *Write-Ahead Logging*, pero no entendí cómo cambiar mi implementación para que funcione en Android Pie (no encontré mucha información), o quizá sea otro el detalle, no lo sé. Ojalá alguien por acá me pueda ayudar.

De antemano, **MUCHAS GRACIAS**.

Comment: tal vez esto te pueda ayudar, en cada deploy de tu aplicación se borran los datos. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4221/debug-as-upgrade-instead-of-new-deployment-to-retain-data

Comment: no evaluaste usar `entity framework` con este tener `migrations` que implementa automaticamente la creacion de la db sino existe, no necesitas nada adicional

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Tú eres para mi una gran persona, siempre veo que ayudas a los demás, desde hace mucho te he visto hacerlo, y mira, qué cosas... ahora acá ayudándome, muchas gracias. Sin embargo, como digo, en versiones anteriores a Android Pie funciona todo muy bien; se crea la base de datos si no existe, almacena los registros, los obtengo, etc. Es con Android Pie que tengo problemas. Saludos, y nuevamente, muchas gracias Tuttini.

Comment: @jtaborga Gracias amigo, pero no es mi solución. Tengo contemplado ello en mis Debugs, pero mi asunto es con los Release, y específicamente con Android Pie (en Oreo, Nougat y Marshmallow funciona todo muy bien; el almacenamiento, las consultas, etc.)